# Parse out user agent the scala way in Play2 application

Tags: regex, scala, playframework, user-agent, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to write a helper method for my Controllers to determine if the device is mobile so that I can load the appropriate template.
This is what I got so far:

```
def isMobile[A](implicit request: Request[A]): Boolean = {
    request.headers.get("User-Agent").exists(agent =>
      if (agent.matches("/(iPhone|webOS|iPod|Android|BlackBerry|mobile|SAMSUNG|IEMobile|OperaMobi)/"))
        true
      else false)
  }
```

This will not work since the user agent do not only provide us with the device but a string
containing a whole lot of nice stuff eg:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A403 Safari/8536.25
```

What is the proper way of parsing this info? Should I create a dictionary with user agents and see if the current string contains one of them? Create a major crazy regexp that matches different user-agents? Maybe there is some scala library that I haven't found that do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything about scala but isn't there some match mode that allows global matches or in other words to look for one of your words in the entire user agent string ?

Comment: Yes there is, thank you for pointing that out. Look at my answer below. Maybe there is some other better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is of course, as Sniffer suggested, do a partial match with `unanchored` like this:

```
val Pattern = "(iPhone|webOS|iPod|Android|BlackBerry|mobile|SAMSUNG|IEMobile|OperaMobi)".r.unanchored

  def isMobile[A](implicit request: Request[A]): Boolean = {
    request.headers.get("User-Agent").exists(agent => {
      agent match {
        case Pattern(a) => true
        case _ => false
      }
    })
  }
```

Maybe there is some other better way?

Comment: I was writing the same solution, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Using pattern from jakob's answer, maybe rewrite the function as:

```
def isMobile[A](implicit request: Request[A]): Boolean =
  request.headers.get("User-Agent") match {
    case Some(Pattern(a)) => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

of if you prefer to work on a String:

```
def isMobile(ua: String) =
  ua match {
    case uaMobilePattern(a) => true
    case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-scala

It's based on https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core which contains data that is used by libraries for many languages. The core of it is https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core/blob/master/regexes.yaml which looks pretty comprehensive.